# Cascading dropdownlist without geting complete data on page load knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I have populated a dropdownlist with values on page load as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/dqUAz/). Then based on the selected value of dropdownlist I need to **get data from server** and populate another dropdownlist.

I tried it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dqUAz/716/) also shown in code below but its not working:

Html code:

```
 <select data-bind="options: countries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedChoice, optionsCaption: 'Choose..', event: {change: getstates}"></select>
    <br/>
    <label data-bind="text: selectedChoice"></label>

    <select data-bind="options: states, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedstate, optionsCaption: 'Choose..'"></select>
    <label data-bind="text: selectedState"></label>
```

JS code:

```
var states1 = [
       {"id": "1", "name": "state1"},
        {"id": "2", "name": "state2"}];
var CountryModel = function(data){
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};
var StateModel = function(data){
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};
var viewModel = function(data) {
   var self = this;
   self.selectedChoice = ko.observable();
    self.selectedstate=ko.observable();
   self.countries = ko.observableArray([
        new CountryModel({id: "1", name: "Russia"}),
        new CountryModel({id: "2", name: "Qatar"})]);
    self.states = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.getstates== function(data) {
        self.states(ko.mapping.fromJS(states1)());
    };

};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.getStates` must be assigned using the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `==`:

```
self.getstates = function(data) {
    self.states(ko.mapping.fromJS(states1)());
};
```

There is a problem with your selected state label. JavaScript is case sensitive so `selectedState` is not the same as `selectedstate`. Since you declared it as `selectedstate` in the view model you must use that:

```
<label data-bind="text: selectedstate"></label>
```

Also in order to use `ko.mapping` you need to include the mapping plugin from here: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping. I just added it from cdnjs.com for my jsfiddle: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/knockout.mapping

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/316mb55x/)

Comment: Is it possible to ensure that my states dropdown is visible only if there is some value in country dropdown?

Comment: Just warp it in a if like [so](http://jsfiddle.net/316mb55x/1/), or you could use the [visible binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) on the dropdown itself.